# How can I get the data back with useState?

Tags: reactjs, api, rest, react-redux

```
  const noticeList = useSelector(state => state.noticeReducer.list) //현재 페이지에 띄워질 공지 리스트

  //page
  const [current, setCurrent] = useState(0);  //현재 페이지
  const pageInfo = useSelector(state => state.noticeReducer.pageInfo);  //전체 페이지 정보
  const [keyword, setkeyword] = useState(null);       //키워드 state
  const [searchedList, setsearchedList] = useState(noticeList);       // 검색 할때만 사용하므로 여기에 사용
  const [active, setactive] = useState("");
  console.log(searchedList)

  const Search = () => {
      const data = axios.post('/noticeList',{
          keyword : keyword,
      })
      .then(res => res.data)
      .catch(err => console.log(err));
  
      setsearchedList(data)
  }
```

```
useEffect(() => {
       return (
           dispatch(getNoticeList(current+1,keyword))  //공지사항 목록 받아오기
       )
   }, [dispatch, current])

//화면에 출력하기 위해 map 함수를 활용
let homeNotice = searchedList.map(
   item => 
  {

      return(
   <NoticeDetail key = {item.noticeId} title = {item.title} active = {active} setactive = {setactive} content = {item.content}/>
      )
      
   }
)
```

I saved the data in Redux in the state with useEffect.
I want to overwrite the data in the same state when searching in the search function. What should I do?

```
Uncaught TypeError: searchedList.map is not a function
```

Comment: What is the type of initialState of "list" in your "noticeReducer"?

Answer (score 1):

You are not using promises correctly you should set the data with the result of the promise, not with the promise:

```
const Search = () => {
  axios
    .post('/noticeList', {
      keyword: keyword,
    })
    .then(({ data }) => setsearchedList(data))
    .catch((err) => console.log(err));
};
```

I am assuming the api call resolves with `data` being an array.